# Getting error 500 with a dynamic route using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, routes, laravel-8

I'm getting error 500 when I try visit a dynamic route. The parameter is optional and is working well when I avoid it.

This is the code

```
Route::get('/{slug?}', function ($request = '') {
    $code = empty($request)? '47ZH2' : $request;
    return view('home', ['code' => $code]);
})->where('slug','^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?');
```

Even I tried without regex but is not working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`/{slug?}` would match all routes since it means match single `/` or any URI after it like `/products`, `/categories` etc. These type of routes aren't recommended as they can create unexpected behaviors in the system and long hours of debugging.

---

If you still wish to keep it, put this route at the end of all routes as it will act as a fallback route if none of the above routes match.

Comment: In fact, I'm just starting the project, so for now, that is the only one.

I need to keep because I need a dynamic route

Comment: @CarlosDiaz Say if you comment this route and have a simple route that echoes something, does it work then? Have you set `debug` as `true` for the application in `.env` or `/config/app.php`?

Comment: Yep! Is working fine without any parameter and the project is on debug in .env

In fact, that route is working fine in my local server, but not on the remote one.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz There could be a lot of possible reasons. Is there a PHP version mismatch, is the local server on Apache and remote one on nginx? Have you checked `/var/logs` for error logs if remote server is on Ubuntu?

Comment: Mine is a Linux hosting with IONOS, using php 8, and the log show only this kind of info "37.14.84.0 - - [18/Sep/2021:14:14:39 +0200] "GET /safasd HTTP/1.1" 500 645 miroyalq.es "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36" "-"" (where "safasd" can be any possible string)

Comment: My local server is apache

Comment: @CarlosDiaz Ok, but this looks like `access.log`, can you check what's inside `error.log`?

Comment: @CarlosDiaz When you say local server, you mean your local machine?

Comment: I call to IONOS and they said me I cannot see error.log, just these files I allowed to see https://prnt.sc/1soyykr

My local server is my local machine, yes. I'm using wamp.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz You may need to upgrade your plan for SSH access.

Comment: My plan already include SSH

Comment: You can login through putty to check them then.

Comment: I did before but I couldn't find error.log, even using the command "whereis". Anyway, thanks for your help bro!

Comment: https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/troubleshooting/checking-your-servers-log-files/

Comment: Unfortunetly that link didn't help me because file "warn" doesn't exist. However, I create a php.ini and I could get a php-error.log in the main project folder. For now that log has some records when I tried to use the command "php artisan cache:clear" but for some reason, namespaces are not working even my php version is 8. Here a screenshot about php-error.log https://prnt.sc/1spyhzb

Comment: Can you post this as a new question and include relevant code?

Comment: Well, after a while, I fix it. From SSH is working for default php 4.4.9, so I did run artisan using php7.4. After cleaning laravel cache, I found out the routes was working fine writing    /index.php/blablabla. So htaccess was not working properly but it was the default one used by laravel. So I changed for wordpress one and I fix it. Anyway I'm going to give your answer like correct because you was helping me a lot. Many thanks bro!

Comment: I am not quite sure how you completely resolved it, but it's great if it works as you wish. Can you untick my answer because future readers might assume my answer is the actual solution whereas you resolved it with changes in .htaccess.